# Movies for visually impaired

Tags: distribution, alternate-version

While I was flying to Asia, in the movies section I saw *Dunkirk* from *Christopher Nolan*. This was a special edition which when played had the audio and commentator describe the scenes and what was happening/displayed. Example: "A man is escaping from bullet fire", etc...

What is the name of this type of movies and which is the movie provider with the largest catalog of these movies?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Audio description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_description)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They're called [Audio Described Movies](http://www.acb.org/adp/movies.html).  Currently, the biggest distributors are:

- Disney Companies (Pixar / Touchstone / 
  Buena Vista / ABC / Marvel)
- Fox
- Paramount
- Sony / Columbia / Screen Gems
- Universal
- Warner Bros (started May 2015)

There weren't many out there until 2010, and even still it is only a very small segment of the market.  However, that segment *is* growing, and about 150 DVD releases in 2016 included an Audio Description track.

Comment: FWIW, I saw that Final Cut Pro X recently added support for creating these. Hopefully other software developers will follow suit and make it much easier for the studios to add them!

Comment: Shouldn't Fox be grouped with Disney now?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg The sale hasn't happened yet.